# How can one imagine the lattice packing of (hyper)spherical particles, in n-dimensional space? like we have the lattices in 3D?

Tags: dimensional-analysis

We can put 4 unit circles inside a square of length 4 units, such that all the circles will touch the boundary and also adjacent circles, and there will be a hollow in between the 4 circles. So we can also consider a 3D cube of length 4 units, and put 8 spheres, where each one will touch the wall, and still be able to put a sphere, at the center of the cube. 
Now, if we can calculate the volume of the mid-spheres (for 2D -> Circle, for 3D -> Sphere, and from then on, Hypershperes), and we find that at the 9th dimension, the 9D-mid-hypershpere just touches the hyper-cube-walls and in the 10th dimension, the mid-sphere, becomes larger than even the 10 Dimensional cube itself. Now my question, how can these be imagined physically, is there any way out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems more suitable for Math SE.

Comment: No, this is also a good problem in Statistical Mechanics. These hypersphere concepts are very useful in that topic.

Comment: Can you explain how nine and ten dimensions apply to statistical mechanics?

Comment: No, not directly that comes, you might know better. I;m learning. I just recently learned the concepts of microstates and it's connection with the hypersphere constructed in the n-dimensional phase space. And then when i started learning about the hyperspheres and it's properties, i came to know about this problem. It might not have direct co-relation with Stat Mech. Don't misunderstand please !